# Cannot load simple Json file with AWS Athena

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a simple JSON file:

```
{'oldname':'mau'}
```

In AWS Athena I wish to read this file and I create the matching table t

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats_json.t (
  `oldname` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://mybucket/stats/';
```

then I try to query:

```
select * from t limit 10;
```

and get an error:

> Query bceb274d-309f-40d5-a893-570de5f4ca4e failed with error code HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code properly.

Comment: I reproduced the given sample and the query worked fine for me. There must be some difference between your sample data and the actual queried data.

Comment: Look for odd formatting and characters in your JSON document. Have you tried the same thing with Hive running locally? That might give you more insight.

Comment: Try with double quotes instead of single ones.  {"oldname":"mau"}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got it to work, so to answer my own question, the problem was with the format of the JSON file. 
It seems AWS Athena (well org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe) is rather picky re: format of the JSON file it reads.

Each JSON record must be entirely on 1 line of text with no spaces between keys and values.

In Python, I generated the JSON records as follows:

```
import json
dStatsRecord = {} # a valid json dict
with open('myfile.json', 'r') as oFile:
  json.dump(dStatsRecord, oFile, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: For anyone struggling with the missing new line delimiter on JSON in Athena, you can replace "}{" with "}\r\n{".  Obvious enough but took me a minute.